# Why is my Google Play ranking so low?

Tags: android, google-play

I recently released [Yarn for Hacker News](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.timmutton.yarn). When I search for "Hacker News" on the google play store, it's the 65th item listed, despite having more reviews and a higher rating than number 4 in the list. It's also behind items that don't have the word "Hacker" or "News" in the title, things that have never been reviewed or have a rating <= 1, or things that haven't been updated in years.

I can't understand for the life of me why it's ranked so low, or what I can do to fix it. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: whilst not a programming question, there doesn't appear to be a more relevant stack exchange to ask this under

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. Not sure if there is another Stack Exchange site that caters to software marketing questions.

Comment: This may not be a programming question, but it definitely is a question likely to be asked by many programmers, who will normally come here for a such answers. Not to have it open shows lack of flexibility, and there is no way questions like this can spoil in a any way the quality of SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is not a "programming" question. I'm providing an answer because I think people search for this here anyway...

Google Play does not release how it ranks apps. If it did, then you would have a different problem.

However, there are a few things you can do to help your ranking, and these are not "rules" but guidelines. This is based on the over 30 apps I have published to Google Play.

1. Don't misread anything I've written. Read and follow Google Play's policies: https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html
2. When people "search" for certain terms, like the ones you describe, Google seems to pay attention to how often people install after searching. This makes sense for everyone.
3. The terms you put in the description are probably more important than your app name. If the app is named "Awesome News" but it is better than your app, shouldn't it be ranked higher? Pay more attention to your description, not so much your title.
4. Low ranking can be caused by poor app performance, misaligned user expectations or other issues that Google cannot measure with precision. They are aware of how many installs and how many people keep an install - maybe even how often they use it. I have several "low ranked" apps that people use frequently. They want more features, better performance, etc. But they keep the apps and use them. Hmm...
5. Rankings also change over time. A recent release can result in a drop in ratings. Should that result in a drop in ranking? Maybe, but Google has a lot more data on things like that than any of us.
6. Apps that have not be updated can mean two things - out of date, or an app that doesn't need to be improved. Google can see the installs, retention, etc. You can't. Don't resent it - work with it. Keep updating your app. Keep your content fresh, etc. Google will notice if the users do.
7. Don't expect Google to "throw you to the top" because of a great app name, or even a great download day. Companies pay a lot of money for those things to try to trick Google. People that are serious about their app and serious about Google don't try to trick them. This means that things don't always move fast, especially with apps that don't "go viral."
8. Pay attention to your "competitors" app descriptions. They may be saying things you haven't thought of saying or mentioning. However, don't just add words to try to help your ranking - there are policies against that.

Maybe you want to hear something else. This isn't magic and Google knows these things should be "common knowledge." They want quality apps, accurate descriptions, and a system that works for the users as well as the developers.

Answer (score 1):

Your app only has 83 reviews at the moment. It may be ranked down yet because of lower popularity. Give it some time and it's rank may increase. Google's algorithms are very unpredictable sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Hi It seems you have uploaded your app in very near past so google may not find your app on higher rank,but still you need to take care of below points to get your app higher in your category

```
SEO friendly keywords in your description
SEO friendly app package name(The quick way to get higher )
Increase user engagement
Share app with your circle and try to searching out from different request on google
Make your app name a unique and SEO friendly
```

You should know that SEO algorithm for Google is not same for Google play store searching so It might not give your correct result all the time.

Good day..!!